# can i create 2 module for a single page by using tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, software-design, tkinter-canvas

i want to make a single page by using Tkinter moreover I want to make it in 2 modules. in that case, I can simplify the code

the code that I've made is

**module 1** (a1.py)

```
from tkinter import *
from a2 import frame


root=Tk()
root.title("voccabulary journel")
root.geometry("700x450")
root.configure(bg='#ff8000')


frame()



root.mainloop()
```

**module 2**(a2.py)

```
from tkinter import *



def frame():
    Grid.rowconfigure(root,0,weight=1)
    Grid.columnconfigure(root,0,weight=1)
    Grid.columnconfigure(root,1,weight=3)

    frame1=Frame(root,background='black')
    frame1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nsew')

    frame2=Frame(root,background='white')
    frame2.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='nsew')

    labeltry1=Label(frame1, text='testing')
    labeltry1.pack()

    labeltry2=Label(frame2,text='tersting')
    labeltry2.pack()
```

I could have written in one module but I just want to simplify it..

i will attach the image of the terminal anyway

[image]

Comment: You have several options here. One can be to add `from __main__ import root` in *a2.py*. But it would be much more **simpel** if you would use classes.

Comment: you should send `root` as argument - `frame(root)` and `def frame(root):`. Don't use in function values which you didn't send as arguments - it makes only problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is good rule: send all values explicitly as arguments.

And this is your problem - in `frame()` you use `root` which you didn't send as argument.

Use:

**a2.py**

```
def frame(root):
    # code
```

**a1.py**

```
frame(root)
```

And this resolves your problem and makes code more readable and simpler to debug.